# TRANSPORT_WSI_SOAP_HEADER_NOT_UNDERSTOOD

Tags: .net

I'm getting this error per an image retrieval purpose:

The content type text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding

(multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported

method is implemented properly. The first 150 bytes of the response were: 'Error 500: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0066E: E_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: An unexpected exception occurred. Message was: null'.

2022-04-08T09:01:15.684 00003C06 WSI FNRCT0059E - ERROR CEWS Listener, unexpected exception

(elapsed request time 15 ms)\ncom.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException:

FNRCT0059E: TRANSPORT_WSI_SOAP_HEADER_NOT_UNDERSTOOD:

A SOAP request included a header http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing:Action with the mustUnderstand attribute,

but that SOAP header is not understood by Content Engine Web Services (CEWS).\n at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.serialization.core.SoapHeaderSerialization.deserialize

(SoapHeaderSerialization.java:97)\n        at com.filenet.apiimpl.wsi.ServiceSessionNst.bReadPastSoapEnvelope(ServiceSessionNst.java:880)\n

HAR file generated from trace:
"Error">Exception [The content type text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 150 bytes of the response were: 'Error 500: com.filenet.api.exception.EngineRuntimeException: FNRCE0066E: E_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: An unexpected exception occurred. Message was: null\r\n'.] occurred while performing search\r\n\n    \n    <script language="javascript">\n        reload('');\n    \n\n\n"

Looking for some insight/solutions.